# how to skip target's recipe if another recipe creates the target in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target, recipe

I have a Makefile, like so:

```
all: build

build:
ifdef USE_CACHE
        @printf ":sigh: failure  :(\nThis should have been skipped by cache's recipe.\n"
endif
        @printf "Building ...\n"
    touch $@

ifdef USE_CACHE
build: cache

cache:
        @printf "Installing cache ...\n"
    touch $@
        @printf "Trying to skip build because cache satisfied it ... \n"
    touch build
endif
```

A default "build" would produce:

```
$ rm build cache; make
Building ...
touch build
```

Which is straightforward and expected, but if the USE_CACHE parameter is defined, the build recipe is still executed, like so:

```
$ rm build cache; make USE_CACHE=1
Installing cache ...
touch cache
Trying to skip build because cache satisfied it ...
touch build
:sigh: failure  :(
This should have been skipped by cache's recipe.
Building ...
touch build
```

I understand this is happening because Make's build graph is established after parsing all of the files and before any recipes are executed, so it's too late to reevaluate the required build recipes after my "cache" recipe is executed.

However, I would like for the "cache" target's recipe to additionally satisfy the "build" target, skipping the "build" recipe's execution, assuming the USE_CACHE target is defined.

Is there some way to achieve this, or is it impossible within GNU Make?

BTW, my real case is much more complicated than the above toy.  For the sake of this question, please assume that the definition of the "build" target's recipe exists within another file that I cannot edit.  I must "include" it as it is to pick up essential, unrelated statements.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding-Makefiles

Comment: It's not clear how much of that makefile you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like the following, which triggers a reread of the Make file and reevaluation of dependencies:

```
    .PHONY: all clean

    all: build
            @true

    clean:
            rm -f build cache sync

    build:
    ifdef USE_CACHE
            @printf ":sigh: failure  :(\nThis should have been skipped by cache's recipe.\n"
    endif
            @printf "Building ...\n"
            touch $@

    ifdef USE_CACHE

    include sync

    cache:
            @printf "Installing cache ...\n"
            touch $@
            @printf "Trying to skip build because cache satisfied it ... \n"
            touch build

    sync: cache
            @printf "Creating cache synchronization file ...\n"
            @printf '$$(info Loading build cache ...  If this works, it should be the last line printed ...)\n' >| $@

    endif
```

There are obvious performance implications from doing a reparse (GNU Make always reparses and reevaluates everything if an included file is created target), but I don't think it is possible to avoid the reevaluation.